# Solution for: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, aes

So, I was messing a bit with pyaes library and I just wanted to encrypt and decrypt a simple string so I created this 2 functions:

```
def aes_encrypt(key, plaintext):
   aes = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCTR(key)
   encrypted_text = aes.encrypt(plaintext)
   print(encrypted_text)

def aes_decrypt(key, encrypted_text):
   aes = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCTR(key)
   decrypted_text = aes.decrypt(encrypted_text)
   print(decrypted_text)
```

The key is generated using key_265 = os.urandom(32)
And I tried to execute the following lines:

```
encrypted_text = aes_encrypt(key_256, "Hi World!")
decrypted_text = aes_decrypt(key_256, encrypted_text)
```

But I am getting this error:`while len(self._remaining_counter) < len(plaintext):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

Someone can explain me why is this happening and tell me a possible solution?

This might be a dupe post but I havent found the solution on other similar threads.

Comment: We need to see a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code. Either `self._remaining_counter` or `plaintext` are `None`, but as we can't see where either are defined, we don't know. For that matter, a counter is usually an int and, if that's so, it wouldn't have a `len`

Comment: @DavidBuck Nope. It's not OP's code, it's something inside the `pyaes` lib. And `counter` is used in the variable name because this specific AES mode is called that.

Comment: Exactly, as @DavidBuck pointed out, I am using pyaes. Plaintext variable is "Hi World!" defined in aes_encrypt() funtion as you can see above

Comment: @DavidBuck So, as I said, the code you wanted is in the lib (and working properly). And the OPs problem was in already posted code. :D (return vs print)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sat here, looking at `pyaes` implementation, thinking "but it should work"...

The problem is your function.

```
encrypted_text = aes_encrypt(key_256, "Hi World!")
```

What is the value of `encrypted_text`? Let's see the function:

```
def aes_encrypt(key, plaintext):
   aes = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCTR(key)
   encrypted_text = aes.encrypt(plaintext)
   print(encrypted_text)
```

There's no `return`. Printing is not the same as returning. The function therefore implicitly returns `None`.

---

Fix: add `return encrypted_text` after `print`. + The same for decryption.

Comment: That worked! I dont know why I didnt realised It was that simple mistake. Thank you so much. Also, is that implementation somewhere near secure? Any improvements?